# Name my class: Pipelined cache? AntiSymetricPipelineCache?

Tags: class, scala, naming, redis

Having trouble coming up with the right name for this class. Basically its a wrapper around a redis data store where writes are "fired off" asynchronously and performed on another thread (to keep the main processing behavior as fast as possible). There are only occasional Get operations and before we can run those we need to make sure that all of the put operations have completed before executing the get operation. During normal operation its very similar to a write-behind cache but it has to wait for flushing/syncing before it can return any data.

Any ideas? I think im missing something obvious here.

Comment: Why don't you make the Gets consult the as-yet unflushed local Puts before submitting the query to the Reddis store?

Comment: Isn't this class somewhat redundant? Redis is an in-memory data store, so you won't gain much by putting an in-memory cache in front of it. If the 100,000 requests/second redis gives you is not enough, you need to be using multiple servers, in which case your in-process cache won't work reliably anyway.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but just a reminder. A lot of people consider classes not easily nameable a smell that points lack of cohesion.

Comment: Aside: Why do you need a separate thread for this? You should be able to let the OS buffer writes for you and only flush+block when you have a read (not sure if there's a Scala client that does this; my redis.net does: http://github.com/rpetrich/redis.net)

Answer (score 3):

If you think of the key -> value mappings as a translation, the Translation Look-aside Buffer (TLB) nomenclature makes sense.